# Session Management in GWT : how to stay connected after refresh

Tags: session, gwt, smartgwt

I have a GWT application with a login box (username and password). Every is fine but I want to improve user experience by keeping him logged when he refresh the page.

Is that possible ?

Can you give me some informations to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stay logged you need to create a session at the server side. After that, in your client side, at `onModuleLoad`, you have to invoke a rule that validates if your user is still connected or not. With that on hand, you can render the UI.

Comment: Do you know where I can find some full example that I can adapted to my solution ?

Comment: The concept is really straightforward. You need to create a session (assuming you're using Java on server-side, [use this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession())) and then create a [GWT RPC](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC) to check if there is a valid session running. At the `onModuleLoad` you invoke that RPC. With the result of that call, you render your UI.